# String adjustment in for-loop

Tags: python, string, list, loops, for-loop

Just a simple question:

```
str = ['blah','blah']
for word in str:
    word = word * 2
print str
```

This just prints ['blah','blah']. Why (I know how to do this, just wondering why this isn't allowed)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that you have created a new string, but not updated the reference in the str list. This means that

```
word = word * 2
```

affects the variable word that has a new address, and this address (reference)
is not updated to the str list. to do that you need to:

```
str[i] = str[i] * 2
```

or

```
word = word * 2
str[i] = word
```

Comment: Immutability is beside the point: if the elements were lists, the issue would be the same:  assigning to a name doesn't change the old value of the name

Answer (score 1):

When you assign a name a new value, it never changes the old value of the name:

```
word = word * 2
```

This takes the value of word, doubles it, and makes it the new value of word.  The old value is unchanged.

Answer (score 0):

In this case, you are asking the array object to be printed. The for loop is not doing anything to the values in the array.

Answer (score 0):

Because there is no standard facility in the language for this.  I.e. you'd want `word` to be sort of a "pointer" to `str[...]` and there's no such thing in Python.  Besides, what if `str` was a generator?